# smart gwt remove hilite and change background color

Tags: css, colors, smartgwt, listgrid

I have a ListGrid for which I have assigned hilite[] for all cells which is working fine.

But now I have change the color of the cell when I select that particular cell/record.

I have created hilites as follows. Here the color of the selected cell doesnt change to blue. But at start its green or red. Please help

```
Hilite[] selected = new Hilite[]{

            new Hilite() {
                {
                    setFieldNames("checkStationName");
                    //setCriteria(new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_FAIL));
                    setCriteria(new Criterion(OperatorId.AND, new Criterion[]{
                              new Criterion("checkStationName", OperatorId.NOT, selectedRecord),
                              new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_FAIL)       
                    }));
                    setTextColor("#FF0000");
                    setCssText("background-color: red;");
                    setId("55");
                }
            }   ,
            new Hilite() {
                {
                    setFieldNames("checkStationName");
                    //setCriteria(new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_SUCCESS));
                    setCriteria(new Criterion(OperatorId.AND, new Criterion[]{
                              new Criterion("checkStationName", OperatorId.NOT_CONTAINS, selectedRecord),
                              new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_SUCCESS)        
                    }));
                    setTextColor("#FF0000");
                    setCssText("background-color: #4CC417;");
                    setId("57");
                }
            }   ,
            new Hilite() {
                {
                    setFieldNames("checkStationName");
                    setCriteria(new Criterion(OperatorId.AND, new Criterion[]{
                              new Criterion("checkStationName", OperatorId.EQUALS, selectedRecord),
                              new Criterion(OperatorId.OR, new Criterion[]{
                                      new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_FAIL),
                                      new Criterion("status", OperatorId.EQUALS, DetectFilesConstants.CHCK_STATUS_SUCCESS)
                              })}));
                    setTextColor("#FF0000");
                    setCssText("background-color: black;");
                    setId("58");
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: I have found out a way to this, but still there some logical bug in this code which I am not able to find out. I am updating my question with my code. Please help.

Comment: Can you explain which colors you want depending of your criteria value and when you set up your listgrid with your hilite.